# Is it possible to spawn Java code from Python, and communicate between the two processes?

Tags: java, python

#### Edit:

I forgot to add initially, but the really big requirement is that this need to be deliverable as an .exe. I'm using PyInstaller now to crunch everything down to an executable, but I have no idea how everything fits together when you start involving multiple programming languages.

---

I have a small gui which I wrote using Python and wxWidgets. The real core of the program, being that it is CPU and Network intensive, I spawn in a new process using the multiprocessing module. That way the gui stays responsive, and the second process it free to run in its own memory/processor space. Finally, I use a thread with a `Multiprocess.Queue` to handle communication between the gui, itself, and the process.

[image]

Now, the problem is that Python is just a touch to slow to handle the main functionality. So I quickly prototyped the build in Java, and I'm getting around a 60% increase in speed. So, for the core logic, I want to port everything to Java.

However, I've put in a *ton* of work into the Gui with Python and WX, so I don't want to rewrite that aspect in Java. So, my question is, how would I go about combining these two separate systems?

The extent of the communication is, for the most part, issuing start and stop commands. The rest is tiny updates that get fed back to the gui just to let the user know what it's currently working on.

Hopefully that all makes sense!

Comment: Without knowing anything of your system, I would suggest a simple method for handling this: create a basic local server and communicate between the processes using it. The advantage is that now you can mix N languages, the problem is that other local processes (unrelated to your system) can potentially instruct your GUI to do things.

Comment: Have you thought about PyPy?  The performance boost from a python JIT might be enought

Comment: @mikeslattery You know, I've never actually checked out pypy. Are the performance gains really that good? I'll have to look up if its compatible with the libraries I'm using.

Comment: @mmgp This is an interesting idea... I've never actually done anything like that before. Do you have any links where I could read up on setting up something like that?

Comment: @Zack this is just basic network communication, I could point to the standard books on it by Steven if you wanted to implement all yourself and known about how it actually works, or you could do a quick search for frameworks that handle the network communication for you. In Python a typical such framework is the one named "twisted". Where the server goes and where the client goes will depend on more details of your system.

Answer (score 0):

> I forgot to add initially, but the really big requirement is that this need to be deliverable as an .exe.

Well I think that is going to pretty much rule out Java.  While it is possible to turn some Java programs into .exe files, it is problematic in many respects ...

I think you would be better off coding the stuff that needs to be real fast in C or C++.  You could either make it a separate executable, or (for better performance) you could access using one of the native library mechanisms; see http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages

---

If the problem you are really trying to address here is GUI responsiveness, you should be able to do the same thing using python threading ... with less coding effort.

Comment: Re: c/C++ I would go this route.. but unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the languages to crank out the code I need in any reasonable amount of time. Re the Threading. It's pretty well threaded now. If you check out the diagram there's a central thread that handles com so it stays responsive. The separate Process is to force the use of a different core. As I mentioned, it's cpu intensive, so I didn't want to waste cycles context switching between threads/gui stuff.